# Procedimiento almacenado que regresa multiples tablas, SQL Server con ADO.NET C# MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, stored-procedure

Estoy tabajando en MVC con .Net Framework C# y SQL Server, se me pide exportar datos de procedimientos Almacenados ya existentes en la BD, que tienen el siguiente formato y regresan datos de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PA_VariasTablas 
    
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 'Hoja1' as Descripcion;

    SELECT id, nombre, apellido FROM nombres;

    SELECT 'Hoja2' as Descripcion

    SELECT id, nombre FROM tblArchivos
END
GO
```

la clase que utilizo para guardar los nombres tiene el siguiente formato

```
    public class clsNombres
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellido { get; set; }
    }
```

si recibo los datos de esta forma solo lee el primer resultado, el que regresa "Hoja 1"

```
            List<clsNombres> lstNombres = new List<clsNombres>();
            string query = "exec PA_VariasTablas";
            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sql);
                sql.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    clsNombres oNombres = new clsNombres();
                    oNombres.id = reader.GetString(0);
                    lstNombres.Add(oNombres);
                }
                reader.Close();
                sql.Close();
            }
            ViewBag.lstNombres = lstNombres;
            return View();
```

¿Hay alguna forma de recibir todos los datos?

PD: El programa, base de datos y procedimiento es solo un ejemplo que diseñé para representar la problemática, y el fin de todo esto es generar documentos de Excel usando EPPlus.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar creando una tabla temporal o variable con campos necesarios para almacenar en ella los datos de todas las tablas con un UNION ALL, algo así:

```
DECLARE
    @Tabla TABLE(
    NomTabla varchar(100),
    Descripcion varchar(max))

INSERT INTO
    @Tabla(
    NomTabla,
    Descripcion)
SELECT
    Q.Tabla,
    Q.Descripcion
FROM(
        SELECT
            'Tabla1' AS Tabla,
            Nombre AS Descripcion
        FROM
            TuTabla1

            UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'Tabla2' AS Tabla,
            NombreProducto AS Descripcion
        FROM
            TuTabla2

            UNION ALL

        SELECT
            'Tabla3' AS Tabla,
            NombreCliente AS Descripcion
        FROM
            TuTabla3 ) AS Q

SELECT * FROM @Tabla
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, ya encontré una solución

Answer (score 0):

ya encontré una solución:

```
string query = "exec PA_VariasTablas";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data, "Nombres");

        //Guardamos en DataTables las diferentes tablas que regresa el Procedimiento Almacenado
        DataTable dtHojas = data.Tables[0];
        DataTable dtNombres = data.Tables[1];
        DataTable dtHojas2 = data.Tables[2];
        DataTable dtArchivos = data.Tables[3];

        //Creamos las listas donde guardaremos los datos
        List<clsNombres> lstNombres = new List<clsNombres>();
        List<clsArchivos> lstArchivos = new List<clsArchivos>();

        //Recorremos los DataTable para asignarlos a las listas
        for (int i = 0; i < dtNombres.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            clsNombres nom = new clsNombres()
            {
                id = dtNombres.Rows[i]["id"].ToString(),
                nombre = dtNombres.Rows[i]["nombre"].ToString(),
                apellido = dtNombres.Rows[i]["apellido"].ToString()
            };
            lstNombres.Add(nom);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dtArchivos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            clsArchivos ar = new clsArchivos()
            {
                id = Convert.ToInt32(dtArchivos.Rows[i]["id"]),
                nombre = dtArchivos.Rows[i]["nombre"].ToString()
            };
            lstArchivos.Add(ar);
        }

        //Pasamos las listas a ViewBag para representarlas en la Vista
        ViewBag.lstArchivos = lstArchivos;
        ViewBag.lstNombres = lstNombres;
        return View();
```

Ahora solo asigno y Recorro los ViewBag dentro de la Vista, y los represento

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    var lstUsuarios = new List<MVC_ADONET.Models.Class.clsNombres>();
    lstUsuarios = ViewBag.lstNombres;
    var lstArchivos = new List<MVC_ADONET.Models.Class.clsArchivos>();
    lstArchivos = ViewBag.lstArchivos;
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    @foreach (var p in lstUsuarios)
    {
        <p>@p.id : @p.nombre</p>
    }
    @foreach (var a in lstArchivos)
    {
        <p>@a.id : @a.nombre</p>
    }
</div>
```

Este seria el resultado final:
[image: Representación de resultados]